# .asp postback address in browser

Tags: html, post, asp-classic, postback

EDITED: [Java httpPost into .asp form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746375/java-httppost-into-asp-form)

I am trying to understand .asp a little
I have this code for the webpage with the login form and a postback action.
Lets assume that the webpage is www.xxx.com/index.asp

```
 <form method="post" id="form1" name="form1" action="">
 <div id="login" class="box">
  <div class="header">Log in</div>
  <div class="content">
   <label for="txtUser">User:</label>
   <input id="txtUser" name="txtUser" type="text" size="13" value="" />
   <label for="txtPassword">Password:</label>
   <input id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" type="password" size="13" value="" />
   <input id="BLogin" name="BLogin" type="submit" value="Log in"  />
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkSave" name="chkSave"   /> <label for="chkSave">Save account</label>
  </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

So as i understand, if I want to fill the fields in the browser window, i must call:

www.xxx.com/index.asp?txtUser=boris&txtPassword=boris&BLogin=Log in

But nothing simmilar is ever executed in the browser. What is wrong with me thinking in that way? :)

EDIT: Seems that not all the input fields must be filled in before doing POST. Probably this depends on the server, when logging in, if service requires for example 'rememmber me' field every time, then it probably must be filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form method is "POST", which means that the form data is sent in a special data block within the HTTP request, not as part of the URL. If you change the method to "GET" the data will be encoded in the query string.

More information: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html

Comment: Do I have to include all the input fields in the request when I will do POST to the server?